# Google Analytics 2.0 beta 4 for IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to use Google Analytics custom variable in my iOS App but i am not able to find a method which will take the custom variable. is there a way to send the custom variable using
Google Analytics 2.0 beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Variables are now called **Custom Dimensions**.

See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/migration and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets

They are sent along with a pageview. (Now called `sendView:`)

In essence, you would do the following:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker setCustom:1 dimension:@"Some Custom Variable"];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendView:@"Some View Controller Name"];
```